# Why Autotools Ignores Installed Static Library?

Tags: static-linking, autotools

I have installed ROHC library ([http://rohc-lib.org](http://rohc-lib.org/)) using following commands during installation:

```
autoreconf -if
./configure --enable-static=yes --enable-shared=no --disable-shared --prefix=/usr
make
make install
```

It successfully installed static (and only static) libraries in `/usr/lib` directory. It contains `librohc.a` and `librohc.la` and no shared-library (i.e. `librohc.so*`).

I am trying to link this library with `OpenVPN`. I added following lines in `configure.ac` of `OpenVPN`:

```
AC_CHECK_HEADERS(
    [rohc/rohc.h rohc/rohc_comp.h rohc/rohc_decomp.h],
    ,
    [AC_MSG_ERROR([ROHC headers not found])]
)

AC_CHECK_LIB(
    [rohc],
    [rohc_compress4],
    ,
    [AC_MSG_ERROR([ROHC library not found])]
)
```

But when I run `make` in `OpenVPN` source directory, I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh ../../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc      -DPLUGIN_LIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib/openvpn/plugins\"  -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-function -g -O2 -std=c99  -lrt -o openvpn argv.o base64.o buffer.o clinat.o comp.o compstub.o comp-lz4.o crypto.o crypto_openssl.o crypto_mbedtls.o dhcp.o error.o event.o fdmisc.o forward.o fragment.o gremlin.o helper.o httpdigest.o lladdr.o init.o interval.o list.o lzo.o manage.o mbuf.o misc.o platform.o console.o console_builtin.o console_systemd.o mroute.o mss.o mstats.o mtcp.o mtu.o mudp.o multi.o ntlm.o occ.o pkcs11.o pkcs11_openssl.o pkcs11_mbedtls.o openvpn.o options.o otime.o packet_id.o perf.o pf.o ping.o plugin.o pool.o proto.o proxy.o ps.o push.o reliable.o route.o schedule.o session_id.o shaper.o sig.o socket.o socks.o ssl.o ssl_openssl.o ssl_mbedtls.o ssl_verify.o ssl_verify_openssl.o ssl_verify_mbedtls.o status.o tls_crypt.o tun.o win32.o rohc.o trunk.o cryptoapi.o  ../../src/compat/libcompat.la -lnsl -lresolv -llzo2 -llz4  -lssl -lcrypto     -ldl  -lrohc 
libtool: link: gcc -DPLUGIN_LIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib/openvpn/plugins\" -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-function -g -O2 -std=c99 -o openvpn argv.o base64.o buffer.o clinat.o comp.o compstub.o comp-lz4.o crypto.o crypto_openssl.o crypto_mbedtls.o dhcp.o error.o event.o fdmisc.o forward.o fragment.o gremlin.o helper.o httpdigest.o lladdr.o init.o interval.o list.o lzo.o manage.o mbuf.o misc.o platform.o console.o console_builtin.o console_systemd.o mroute.o mss.o mstats.o mtcp.o mtu.o mudp.o multi.o ntlm.o occ.o pkcs11.o pkcs11_openssl.o pkcs11_mbedtls.o openvpn.o options.o otime.o packet_id.o perf.o pf.o ping.o plugin.o pool.o proto.o proxy.o ps.o push.o reliable.o route.o schedule.o session_id.o shaper.o sig.o socket.o socks.o ssl.o ssl_openssl.o ssl_mbedtls.o ssl_verify.o ssl_verify_openssl.o ssl_verify_mbedtls.o status.o tls_crypt.o tun.o win32.o rohc.o trunk.o cryptoapi.o  ../../src/compat/.libs/libcompat.a -lrt -lnsl -lresolv -llzo2 -llz4 -lssl -lcrypto -ldl /usr/lib/librohc.so
gcc: /usr/lib/librohc.so: No such file or directory
```

Yes, `/usr/lib/librohc.so` does not exist, but `/usr/lib/librohc.a` exists. Why is it not linking with the static library `/usr/lib/librohc.a` at absence of `.so` ?

You may ask me why I am not installing shared libs of ROHC; answer is that I want to force static linking with ROHC, and when it is done I will uninstall ROHC libs.

If someone could show me how to do this static linking without installing ROHC first (like adding dependency to `configure.ac` or `Makefile.am` of OpenVPN), it would be better for me.

Note that, both `OpenVPN` and `ROHC` library require `autotools`.

Comment: I solved the problem by just making `/usr/lib/librohc.so` a symbolic link to `/usr/lib/librohc.a`. It worked however.

Comment: After a brief look at `openvpn` source, you need to modify `Makefile.am` in `src/openvpn`, adding, say, `$(OPTIONAL_ROHC_LIS)` in the same way the other `_LDADD` library deps are added. You also want `$path/librohc.la`, that **libtool** is aware of, so that it links a static library. (This required `autoreconf -fvi` to regenerate the build system... A symlink to a shared library for a static library is an inappropriate hack. `libtool` ensures that `librohc.la` (a meta-data file) will resolve a static vs shared object. Without your complete build system,  it's difficult to to be certain...

Answer (score 0):

I specified `--libdir=/usr/lib64` with `./configure` of ROHC library and finally the build system used the static library `librohc.a` when linking with OpenVPN. I installed ROHC with:

```
autoreconf -if
./configure --enable-static --disable-shared --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64
make
make install
```

Now it installs the library as `/usr/lib64/librohc.a` and Compilation of OpenVPN successfully finds and links to it.

And surely, it took place in a 64 bit machine (CentOS 6). In a 32 bit environment (OpenWrt in a 32-bit MIPS router) where there is nothing like `/usr/lib64`, the problem in the question does not take place.

Comment: Ok, so the wanted library was not, in fact, installed in the default library search path for the system you were using.  That explains almost everything.  The only remaining question is why your symlink hack actually resolved the issue for you, but it is not out of the question that, as GCC is installed on your machine, its search path for shared libraries is effectively more inclusive than its search path for static ones.